# Moving Windows between laptops

Tags: windows-10

I have two laptops. One is very small with a touchscreen, with Windows 10 and Office. The other is bigger, no touchscreen and has Elementary OS.

I wanna switch. I'm not content with Windows on the small PC, it doesn't work very well. Jide recently [released Remix OS for PC](http://www.jide.com/en/remixos-for-pc) and I want to put that instead of the Windows. I think it would run better.

However, I don't want to lose the Windows, so I want to install it on my other laptop (probably alongside Elementary). Is there a simple way to do this? (and no, I don't have the original box that came with the small laptop, nor do I have the serial number and such).

Note - I'm not asking about files. I can transfer those easily enough. I just want to transfer the license somehow for Windows and Office as well.

Comment: This requires you purchase a Windows 10 license, the license you have, cannot be transferred to your other machine

Comment: @Ramhound just like that? Cannot be transferred at all?

Comment: OEM license cannot be transfered, the installation can be, but you still need a license.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no easy way to transfer installed licenses as these licenses will be added to your windows registry and whenever you install windows it will create a new registry.

Still 2 possible solutions:-
1- If you don't want elementary os you can just exchange hard-disks of your laptops, and update or reinstall device drivers (Sometimes It will corrupt windows).

2- Create an image of your disk and later whenever you want restore using this image.

Or

2- Create partition image using norton ghost or any other tool and install it to your other laptop but it will replace everything from your other laptop.

See these too

http://www.howtogeek.com/239815/why-cant-you-move-a-windows-installation-to-another-computer/

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-hk/windows/restore-computer-from-system-image-backup#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score -1):

To answer short: there is no easy way to move windows 10 to another computer.

First of all, Windows 10 does not yet have "Windows Easy Transfer". You could try third party app http://pcmoverfree.azurewebsites.net/ to move your files from one computer to another.

Before that you would need to install Windows 10 on your other laptop. Also would need to have a separate drive or partition made for it. I am not familiar with the Elementary OS and the boot records for it, but I would assume it could work out with Windows 10 running in parallel.

Comment: I don't care about the files. I can easily move the important stuff with an external drive. I know how to install Windows on the new laptop alongside Elementary, it's not very difficult. I'm just asking if there's a way to move the license for the windows and office

Comment: You may want to check if you can get the key out of the registry: http://www.howtogeek.com/206329/how-to-find-your-lost-windows-or-office-product-keys/

Comment: Ok, but can I then wipe windows and casually use those when installing Windows on the other laptop? Would they work just like that? Don't I have to do something? I mean, it makes sense that you wouldn't be able to use a license more than once, right?

Comment: If you wont use your old Windows 10 laptop, there is no problem if you will be using same license key. Legally wise not sure how it goes here, but technically it is possible.

Comment: Actually Windows 10 DOES have the easy transfer program, just as an official FREE version of a third-party application, but that doesn't help the author because that has nothing to do with moving the installation and license to another machine just the user  profile

Comment: That is incorrect, it DOES NOT HAVE. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-easy-transfer-is-not-available-in-windows-10 They partnered with the third party provider, as I did mention in response

Comment: @MaksimLuzik - Right?  I consider [official (optional) third-party software](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/transfer-your-data) to be part of Windows if its installed.  PCMover still won't transfer the Windows 10 installation though which is what the author wanted.